# Наречие "интегрально"

Tags: пунктуация

Очевидно, что здесь нужен какой-то знак, но не лучше ли здесь будет смотреться тире?

Интегрально, в чем состоит итог 20-летней деятельности...

Интегрально – в чем состоит итог 20-летней деятельности...

Answer (score 2):

"Интегрально" в вашей фразе примерно означает "вообще" или "и вообще".
*И вообще, в чем состоит...*

Конечно, "интегрально" здесь ни к селу ни к городу. Убрать нельзя?

Answer (score 1):

Структура предложения неясна.

Существует наречие "интегрально" (в целом, в совокупности, суммарно). Один из вариантов начала предложения: "В чем интегрально состоит итог 20-летней деятельности...".

Можно ли  наречие "интегрально" употребить в качестве вводного слова? Чтобы ответить на этот вопрос,  надо видеть предложение полностью.

ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ

Если ничего не менять, то лучше оставить запятую: "Интегрально, в чем состоит итог 20-летней деятельности Вашей компании?". Употребление слова не очень привычное, но в таком виде лучше понимается его вводный характер.

Comment: Да, согласен с Софией. Без контекста ответить сложно.

Comment: Это вопрос: Интегрально, в чем состоит итог 20-летней деятельности Вашей компании?

Comment: Тогда уж точно лучше сказать: "В чем интегрально состоит итог 20-летней деятельности Вашей компании?". Наречие "интегрально" в роли вводного слова не замечено. Но можно попробовать использовать такое выражение: "А если говорить интегрально, в чем состоит итог...".

Comment: Спасибо. Первый вариант мне больше нравится: "В чем интегрально..."